# Keras L2 regularization makes the network not learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a simple model for the MNIST dataset. A single hidden layer of 36 neurons.

```
NUM_CLASSES = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128
EPOCHS = 100

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape = x_train.shape[1:]),

    layers.Dense(units = 36, activation = activations.sigmoid, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),

    layers.Dense(units = NUM_CLASSES, activation = activations.softmax)
])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss      = losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics   = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs = EPOCHS,
                    verbose = 2,
                    validation_data = (x_val, y_val))
```

Without the `l2` part everything works but as soon as I try to use regularization it all goes sideways and the accuracy consistently stays at 10%:

```
Epoch 1/300
391/391 - 1s - loss: 2.4411 - accuracy: 0.0990 - val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1064

Epoch 2/300
391/391 - 0s - loss: 2.3374 - accuracy: 0.1007 - val_loss: 2.3031 - val_accuracy: 0.1064

Epoch 3/300
391/391 - 0s - loss: 2.3178 - accuracy: 0.1016 - val_loss: 2.3041 - val_accuracy: 0.1064

Epoch 4/300
391/391 - 0s - loss: 2.3089 - accuracy: 0.1045 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.1064

Epoch 5/300
391/391 - 0s - loss: 2.3051 - accuracy: 0.1060 - val_loss: 2.3030 - val_accuracy: 0.1064
```

This happens both when I manually give `regularizers.l2` as an argument and when I give `"l2"` as an argument.

Why exactly does this happen and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried larger values for regularizers such as `regularizers.l2(0.01)`? Maybe the value is too small.

Comment: @tritsu I did, same result. The default value for `l2` is `0.01`. But why would this matter. A value of `0.0` for the regularization value should simply mean that no regularization is applied so it is as if no regularization was given. But if I actually do not give this argument the code works fine.

Comment: "Without the l2 part everything works" what are the train and val accuracy numbers in that case? Also what kind of preprocessing have you done on images?

Comment: Could you try remove Dropout, when using l2 regularization?

Comment: @today  about 94% No preprocessing except making the pixel values be in the interval [0,1]

Comment: try changing activation function in the dense layer with 36 units from sigmoid to relu

Answer (score -1):

I suspect with a high dropout rate of .5 adding regularization will prevent the network from learning. Both dropout and regularization are a means to prevent over fitting. Try using a lower dropout rate with regularization and see if the network trains properly. My experience to date is that dropout is more effective at controlling over fitting than regularizers.

Comment: No change if I do it without dropout.